# How do I test the headset microphone on android, whilst ignoring the phone's internal microphone?

Tags: audio, 7.0-nougat, headphones, microphone, headset

I can't find any apps that do this on Google Play and testing the microphone in Discord isn't any help either.

Comment: use a long long cable ;)

Comment: If you want to see if the headset microphone works at all just touch it with your finger. This will cause sounds that are only recordable by the microphone you touch.